# How to get content through IHttpActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a simple method which returns a `IHttpActionResult`:

```
public IHttpActionResult invokeGetAction(HttpRequestMessage _request, String 
 _forResource)
{
    return new GetResourceActionResult(_request, _forResource);
}
```

The implementation of `GetResourceActionResult` looks as follows:

```
public class GetResourceActionResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly HttpRequestMessage _request;
    private readonly string _location;

    public GetResourceActionResult(HttpRequestMessage request, string location)
    {
        _request = request;
        _location = location;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = _request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(_location);
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

I want to call the `invokeGetAction()` inside a System.Web.Http.ApiControllers' Get() method to just foward the present request to another API like

```
[Authorize]
[Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    return _someService.invokeGetAction(Request, "http://mockingsvc.../api/songs");
}
```

And I can see the HttpStatusCode.OK so I assume I'm not failing right now. But I have no idea where and how to get the content data delivered by the `invokeGetAction()` - somewhere in `ExecuteAsync()`?

Comment: From what I can see from your code snippets, I don't see you setting any content for the response to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok yes, I forgot something... ;-) My code is now

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task.FromResult(Execute(_resourceUri));
}

public HttpResponseMessage Execute(String resourceUri)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(resourceUri);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            return client.GetAsync("api/songs").Result;
        }
    }
```

and it works like a charm.